# Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '18-02-1962' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)

Tags: mysql

Returned the following error on mysql when importing the data:

> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '18-02-1962' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '08-12-1958' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '29-08-1973' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '19-09-1947' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '03-03-1965' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '01-07-1973' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '29-05-1970' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect date value: '09-01-1968' for column 'birthdate' at row 1", 1292)
> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'reports_to' at row 1", 1366)

The following is the code used to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
reports_to INT NULL,
birthdate DATETIME,
hire_date DATETIME,
address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
state varchar(50) NOT NULL,
country varchar(50) NOT NULL,
postal_code varchar(15) NOT NULL,
phone varchar(50) NOT NULL,
fax varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
email varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

No idea why this error occured!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Date Data Types
MySQL comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:

```
DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
YEAR - format YYYY or YY
```

If the table column is in data type is *DATE* then data should be in ***YYYY-MM-DD*** format

refer https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

the datatype for birthdate is DATETIME which is literally date + time. you are providing the wrong input.
you probably want to change the datatype to DATE

you can refer to this:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html